# How to do rolling applying a function using all historic data up to a date?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a monthly time-series pandas dataframe and would like to do rolling using all past data e.g. I have data from 1990-01-01 to 2020-01-01. Then I'd like to start from 1999-12-31 and do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['1990-01-01':'1999-12-31'].apply(myfun)
df['1990-01-01':'2000-01-31'].apply(myfun)
df['1990-01-01':'2000-02-29'].apply(myfun)
df['1990-01-01':'2000-03-31'].apply(myfun)
```

My data is monthly so it should be simpler given that every month in a row. How would this work with rolling? I didn't find a clear cut way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for

```
df.expanding().apply(myfunc)
```

Answer (score 1):

the rolling function can apply to a Pandas Series. You can caluclate the rolling mean, or any other function that you need. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

serie  = pd.Series([1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0])
serie.rolling(window=3).mean()
```

output:
Out[19]:
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    1.000000
3    0.666667
4    0.333333
5    1.000000
6    1.000000
7    0.666667
dtype: float64

it can be combined with lag and groupby for different time series calculation.

In your example, you could do something like:

```
df['your_column_with_sales_or_any_values'].rolling(window=3).mean()
```

You will need to set up a window convinient for your problem